# Is it possible to execute an Ingest PipeLine in an ElasticSearch Update?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, pipeline, nest

I'm using **NEST** to comunicate with **ElasticSearch**.
In an Index operation I can especify the PipeLine to execute:

```
var insertDocument = client.Index<Document>(docInsert,
s => s.Index(idxName)
.Pipeline("attachments"));
```

Is it possible to execute an Ingest PipeLine in an ElasticSearch Update?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. [Pipelines can only be specified on index and bulk (index operations).](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html)

Comment: It seems like it is potentially possible with an update_by_query api https://www.shubho.dev/devops/elastic-search-update-by-query-with-ingest-pipeline ?

Comment: @DavidKong yes, pipelines are now supported in update by query API (but were not at time of this answer).

Comment: That's a great development, perfect

Comment: Now they just need to support bulk update by query...